# Using bplapply for batch parallel processing

Tags: r, bioconductor

Suppose that I have 8000 files, if I try to process these files using bplapply with number of workers = 4, each workers will take in 2000 files. For some reasons, I do not know why there is memory accumulation, thus I decided to load the files in batch. For example, I hope to load only 500 files per worker (which means 500 * 4 = 2000 files once) before loading the next batch. How can I accomplish this **without looping over the bplapply**?

Comment: Create an outside for loop that fetches 500 files, run them through bplapply, rinse, repeat.

Comment: I try to avoid this approach, @RomanLuštrik. Is there any internal parameters or any other functions that can do this?

Comment: One way would be to split the list of files and operate on that list. But it's essentially doing the same thing as a loop. Unfortunately I'm not intimately familiar with BiocParallel functionality to give a more informed answer, sorry.